# How can I fix my 2D char array grid rendering to remove 'null' values?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to render a grid, specifically a 2D char array with 9 rows and 17 columns. The left-most column and the top-most row are used for displaying the grid coordinates A-H and 1-8.

However every time I render the grid there are these 'null' values that appear. Like so: ␀␀1␀2␀3␀4␀5␀6␀7␀8. These appear in every space in the grid.

here is the section of code:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Renderer {

    private static final char[] COL_LABELS = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'} ;
    private static final char[] ROW_LABELS = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'} ;

    private static final char DEFAULT = '·' ;
    private static final char HIT = '◉' ;
    private static final char MISS = '~' ;

    public static final int GRID_WIDTH = 17;
    public static final int GRID_HEIGHT = 9;

    private static int cellCol2GridCol(int cellCol) {
        return 2 + (2 * cellCol);
    }

    private static int cellRow2GridRow(int cellRow) {
        return 1 + cellRow ;
    }

    public static char[][] renderEmptyGrid() {
    char[][] grid = new char[GRID_HEIGHT][GRID_WIDTH];

    // Draw the header row
    for (int cellCol = 0; cellCol < GRID_HEIGHT - 1; cellCol++) {
        int gridCol = cellCol2GridCol(cellCol);
        grid[0][gridCol] = COL_LABELS[cellCol];
    }

    // Draw the header column
    for (int cellRow = 0; cellRow < GRID_HEIGHT - 1; cellRow++) {
        int gridRow = cellRow2GridRow(cellRow);
        grid[gridRow][0] = ROW_LABELS[cellRow];
    }

    // Fill the rest of the grid with the DEFAULT character
    for (int i = 1; i < GRID_HEIGHT; i++) {
        for (int j = 2; j < GRID_WIDTH; j += 2) {
            grid[i][j] = DEFAULT;
        }
    }

    return grid;
}
```

There are these two helper methods also:

A static cellCol2GridCol method, which accepts a valid cell column (i.e an int from 0-7) as input, and returns the corresponding column index in the 2d array (i.e. an int from 0-16).

A static cellRow2GridRow method, which accepts a valid cell row (i.e. an int from 0-7) as input, and returns the corresponding row index in the 2d array (i.e. an int from 0-8).

I started by filling the array with space characters. And then worked on replacing some of the spaces with the correct character.

I know I can't just put a number like 1 or 2 directly into a char array; it will end up printing the ASCII character that has a code of 1 or 2, rather than 1 or 2. So I used the characters stored in Renderer.COL_LABELS instead.

Comment: `javascript` is not `java`. [Tags updated.]

Comment: *I started by filling the array with space characters.* And what was wrong with that?        `for(char[] row : grid) { Arrays.fill(row, ' '); }`

Comment: Consider including an example of what you expect/want it to look like.

Answer (score 0):

The *null* values are because some of the cells contain no data.

Here is *grid[0]*.

```java
[ ,  , 1,  , 2,  , 3,  , 4,  , 5,  , 6,  , 7,  , 8]
```

The values at the odd indices were never assigned a *char* value, thus are still *null*—or more accurately, *'\u0000'*.

This is happening because you're incrementing by *2* at the following *for-loop*.

```java
for (int i = 1; i < GRID_HEIGHT; i++) {
    for (int j = 2; j < GRID_WIDTH; j += 2) {
        grid[i][j] = DEFAULT;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if you are intending to have the additional, empty cells.
You have *GRID_WIDTH* set to *17*, yet the columns are from *1* to *8*.

Here is another approach, to generating the same grid.

```java
char[][] grid = new char[9][9];
grid[0][0] = ' ';
for (int row = 1; row < 9; row++)
    Arrays.fill(grid[row], '·');
for (int cell = 1; cell < 9; cell++)
    grid[0][cell] = Character.forDigit(cell, 10);
for (int row = 1; row < 9; row++)
    grid[row][0] = (char) ('A' + (row - 1));
```

And, you can print the grid with the following.

```java
for (char[] row : grid) {
    for (char cell : row) System.out.printf("%2s", cell);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output

```
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
 A · · · · · · · ·
 B · · · · · · · ·
 C · · · · · · · ·
 D · · · · · · · ·
 E · · · · · · · ·
 F · · · · · · · ·
 G · · · · · · · ·
 H · · · · · · · ·
```